# Python: Test if value can be converted to an int in a list comprehension

Tags: types, casting, int, python

Basically I want to do this;

```
return [ row for row in listOfLists if row[x] is int ]
```

But row[x] is a text value that may or may not be convertible to an int

I'm aware that this could be done by:

```
try:
    int(row[x])
except:
    meh
```

But it'd be nice to do it is a one-liner.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you only deal with integers, you can use [`str.isdigit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

> Return true if all characters in the string are digits and there is at least one character, false otherwise.

```
[row for row in listOfLists if row[x].isdigit()]
```

Or if negative integers are possible (but should be allowed):

```
row[x].lstrip('-').isdigit()
```

And of course this all works only if there are no leading or trailing whitespace characters (which could be stripped as well).

Comment: Only with *non-negative* integers, as `-` is not a digit. But this is propably the best solution if it works. Otherwise, a regex that allows a leading `-` is nearly as readable.

Comment: Wouldn't `.lstrip('-')` give a wrong (read: `abs`'d) result? Propably not what OP wants.

Comment: @delnan: It is only for testing. The orginal value is preserved (or I don't understand your comment).

Comment: Note that `.lstrip('-')` will strip multiple leading hyphens, leading to the conclusion that `'--1'` is a valid number.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a regular expression? (use `re.compile` if needed):

```
import re
...
return [row for row in listOfLists if re.match("-?\d+$", row[x])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
return filter(lambda y: y[x].isdigit(), listOfLists)
```

or if you need to accept negative integers

```
return filter(lambda y: y[x].lstrip('-').isdigit(), listOfLists)
```

As fun as list comprehension is, I find it less clear in this case.