# How to write an if condition such that python should execute if statement if the element in a listcan be converted to type int

Tags: python, list, if-statement, types

How can i write the code for an if condition where i want to see if i can convert the type of an element in a list to int. If its possible, then if condition should be executed.Otherwise, it should go to else statement

For eg:

```
lst=['@','#','^','%','20']

''' Now i am going to iterate through the list and check if i can convert the elements  to type int. If it can be converted then i know there is a number in the list and i do some operations on the number'''

for ele in lst:
    if(type(int(ele)=='int'):
        #do some operation on the number eg:20/2 and print the value
    else:
        continue
```

Please give me an idea as to how to write the if condition.

Comment: You should instead `try` to convert the element to int and proceed if successful, `except` that you do something else when that fails with a `ValueError`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Test if value can be converted to an int in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606585/python-test-if-value-can-be-converted-to-an-int-in-a-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if each element is an int using a try block in a helper function `is_int`:

```
def is_int(s):
    try: 
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

lst = ['@', '#', '^', '%', '20']
for s in lst:
    if is_int(s):
        int_s = int(s)
        print(f'{int_s}/2 = {int_s/2}')
    else:
        continue
```

**Output:**

```
20/2 = 10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert to `int` and catch the error:

```
for ele in lst:
    try:
        val = int(ele)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    else:
        print(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.isdigit()`+a list comprehension (perfect couple ;-):

```
lst=['@','#','^','%','20']
[str(x).isdigit() for x in lst]
```

**Caveat**: does not work for float strings, for floats:

```
[str(x).replace('.','').isdigit() for x in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is :

```
if isinstance(ele,int)
```

```
lst = ['@', '#', '^', '%', 20]

for ele in lst:
    if isinstance(ele,int):
        print("This is int: " + str(ele))
    else:
        print("This is not int: " + ele)
```

Very simple and easy.

Comment: Thank you. But I am checking if the elements can be converted to int type. not if the element is of type int.

Comment: Oh sorry about that :)